# How to render an orthographic image with an alpha mask in cycles?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, image, transparency

I have created a simple grass scene with materials created in cycles.

[image]

I would like to render this image with an alpha mask and without any lighting. How would I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the camera to Orthographic view.

[image: cmaera settings]

Then render it as a *PNG* with RGBA.
Under the *Film* tab check the check mark for *transparent*.

[image]

Now if you need separate black and white image for the alpha mask.
Go to the compositer. Plug the *Alpha* from the render layer in to the *Image* socket of the *Composite* node.
[image]